# How to filter out the blank values in vsc in python

Tags: python, pandas, nan

I’m having trouble with filtering out the blanks in vsc. I need to replace the blanks with an integer value, say “-1” but some of these blanks are mixed in with the “N/A” values, but I need to keep the “N/A” separate. What is the best way of going about this?
[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQoKH.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXTFQ.jpg)

I’ve tried converting the Condition Overall to strings and then tried finding the blank values from there using df.loc but it’s still not working. The nan values are all mixed up.

Comment: Can you share your code and input data please.

Comment: Sounds like you are using Pandas so have you read this?  https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/missing_data.html

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly.
Text allows for quick copy and pictures do not.
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Condition Overall': ['1', '', 'N/A', '2', np.nan, 'Average', '']
})
df['Condition Overall'].replace('', -1, inplace=True)
df['Condition Overall'].replace(np.nan, 'N/A', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

Output

```
  Condition Overall
0                 1
1                -1
2               N/A
3                 2
4               N/A
5           Average
6                -1
```

You can directly do so by removing it one by one